# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: google-chrome, iis

I am trying to call API, web site is served from IIS, but I get

> **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

I tried,

1. checking the ssl certificate for this web site, I see certificate hasn't expired
2. deleted all the cookies and loaded Chrome

Still the issue persist, tried with Mozilla. I see same issue

Note: I am able to access this web site locally in the server. It doesn't show this error.

Comment: What's the binding? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: take look at the iis logs for the site and get more idea about the issue and try to increase the iis site connection time out limit by from the advance setting. [image](https://imgur.com/RxJRGZg)